# Why can't I retrieve the entities I've just persisted?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jax-ws, hsqldb

I've got this web service that basically queries the database and returns all persisted entities. For testing purposes, I've created a TestDataManager that persists 2 example entities after Spring context is loaded (BTW, I'm using JAX-WS, Spring, Hibernate and HSQLDB).

My TestDataManager looks like this:

```
@Component
public class TestDataManager {

@Resource
private SessionFactory sf;

@PostConstruct
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void insertTestData(){
    sf.openSession();
    sf.openSession().beginTransaction();
    sf.openSession().persist(new Site("site one"));
    sf.openSession().persist(new Site("site two"));
    sf.openSession().flush();
}
}
```

My JAX-WS endpoint looks like this:

```
@WebService
public class SmartBrickEndpoint {

@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;

public Set<Site> getSitesForUser(String user){
    return getSiteService().findByUser(new User(user));
}

private ISiteService getSiteService(){
    ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) context.getMessageContext().get("javax.xml.ws.servlet.context");
    return (ISiteService) BeanRetriever.getBean(servletContext, ISiteService.class);
}
}
```

This my Service class:

```
@Component
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class SiteService implements ISiteService {

@Resource
private ISiteDao siteDao;

@Override
public Set<Site> findByUser(User user) {
    return siteDao.findByUser(user);
}
}
```

This is my DAO:

```
@Component
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class SiteDao implements ISiteDao {

@Resource
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public Set<Site> findByUser(User user) {
    Set<Site> sites = new LinkedHashSet<Site>(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Site.class).list());

    return sites;
}
}
```

This is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="br.unirio.wsimxp.dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="br.unirio.wsimxp.service"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="br.unirio.wsimxp.spring"/>

<bean id="applicationDS" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:sites"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="applicationDS" />

    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">on_close</prop>
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>-->
            <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

This is what's going on now:

1. when the app is deployed, TestDataManager#insertTestData kicks-in (due to @PostConstruct) and persist does not raise any exception. I should have 2 entities in the DB by now.
2. Afterwards, I invoke the endpoint by a SOAP client, and the request goes all the way up to the DAO. The Hibernate invocation does not raise any exception, but the returned list is empty.

The odd thing is, in TestDataManager, if I switch from `sf.openSession()` to `sf.getCurrentSession()`, I get an error message: "No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here".

What I am doing wrong here? Why is the query "not seeing" the persisted entities? Why do I need to invoke `sf.openSession()` on TestDataManager although it's annotated with `@Transactional`?

I have done some tests with `hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread` in application.xml, but then I just switch problems in each class. I'd like not needing to manually invoke `sf.openSession()` and leave that for Hibernate to take care.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Have you solved your problem? Have you tried the solution below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to commit the transaction on `insertTestData`:

```
@PostConstruct
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void insertTestData(){
    Session session = sf.openSession();

    session.persist(new Site("site one"));
    session.persist(new Site("site two"));
    session.flush();
    session.close();
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, I had to out it aside and move forward with a different approach, but the odd thing is: why do I need to open a session and begin a txn if I have it annotated with @Transactional? That doesn't make any sense to me, after all @PostConstruct is invoked, which makes me think spring configs are ok and the class is a "correct" bean. Does it make any sense?

Comment: No you don't need to begin a transaction and make use of `@Transactional` at the same time if all you want is to persist a couple of entities. My answer just addressed the fact that you were opening 5 sessions and not committing the inner transaction. I have edited the solution and removed `session.beginTransaction()` and `tx.commit()`. Please try and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

(I use hibernate in jpa mode)

I think your transactional annotations are not intercepted properly. Have you specified the HibernateVendorAdapter? In jpa+hibernate the integration is not fully setuped without it! Most likely you are missing this declaration.

After you should be able to autowire directly the Session instead of the Factory.

As a side note. If you use opensession in your code at least call it only once and keep the session in a variable. Else you are always opening a new one on each call i believe.

Answer (score 1):

```
@PostConstruct
public void insertTestData(){
  Obejct o = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager).execute(new TransactionCallback() {
    public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
      //Your code here
    }
  });
}
```

source: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?58337-No-transaction-in-transactional-service-called-from-PostConstruct&p=194863#post194863

Comment: I tried that, but the data just doesn't show up on the database, am I missing something?  https://gist.github.com/felipecao/5968341

Comment: Yep, you are missing session.persist. Where is?